# Accessing to content of nativeWindow loaded via htmlLoader in flex AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm sending a request to a specific url which in response gives me plain text which I am able to display in nativeWindow with the code shown below:

```
    public function HtmlContentWindow(urlString:String, urlMethod:String = URLRequestMethod.GET)
    {
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
        urlReq.method=urlMethod;

        var initOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
        initOptions.owner=NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow;
        super(initOptions);

        var htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
        htmlLoader.width=this.width;
        htmlLoader.height=this.height;

        var nativeMenu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
        var item:NativeMenuItem = new NativeMenuItem("Save content");


        nativeMenu.addItem(item);


        this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        this.stage.align="TL";
        this.stage.addChild(htmlLoader);
        this.visible=true;

        htmlLoader.load(urlReq);

    //  item.data=  <- no idea how can I get reference to the actual text loaded into the native window
        item.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,saveContent);
        this.menu= nativeMenu;


    }
```

I want to implement that user can save the text on his local device, but I can't get a hold of the actual text in the window. I know it's possible when the content is html via docWindow.document.getElementByTag etc but it's not an option in this case.

I've tried to debug it and trace all the fields of objects I'm using but I failed to find the content field.

Comment: Don't use **HTMLLoader** then. If you load plain text only, you can load it with **URLLoader** (which give you the full access to the loaded data) and display it in a plain **TextField**.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem.